# Hilos y procesos

Tags: hilos, proceso

Estoy estudiando un poco respecto a hilos y procesos y, tras informarme un poco, hay ciertas cuestiones que no encuentro ningún libro o curso que resuelva.

Cuando se habla de procesos se dice que un proceso se ejecuta en un procesador o CPU.

Cuando se habla de hilos se dice que un hilo se ejecuta en un núcleo del procesador.

Por tanto, me surgen las siguientes dudas:

- 1º: ¿El proceso en qué parte del procesador se ejecuta? O realmente lo que se ejecuta del proceso siempre son los hilos y todos los procesos tienen mínimo un hilo. En este caso lo que se ejecutaría del proceso siempre sería este hilo en el núcleo. (esto es deducción mía porque no encuentro información de esto en ningún sitio)
- 2º: ¿En un procesador de varios núcleos se pueden ejecutar de forma paralela varios hilos de distintos procesos?
- 3º: ¿En un núcleo de un procesador se pueden ejecutar de manera concurrente varios hilos de distintos procesos?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Respuesta rápida: 1.- en la unidad de control, que posteriormente desviará el trabajo a la unidad aritmético lógica, de coma flotante o los puertos de entrada salida según sea la instrucción que le toque ejecutar. 2.- Sí. 3.- No(1). (1) En procesadores multihilo (2 en arquitectura x86_64 y hasta 4 en procesadores PowerPC) se podría considerar que sí, pero realmente tiene limitaciones al trabajar la misma parte de ese núcleo físico con cierto tipo de tareas al mismo tiempo en cada una de las "hebras".

Comment: En [esta liga](https://www.intel.la/content/www/xl/es/gaming/resources/hyper-threading.html) hay una buena explicación.

Comment: Las [*Unidades de Proceso*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidad_de_proceso) ejecutan *Tareas*, la [*Unidad de Control*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidad_de_control) ejecuta instrucciones. Una aplicación (proceso principal) puede tener subprocesos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que considerar la definición de "proceso" por parte del sistema operativo, no por parte del procesador. Te recomiendo leer, al menos, el [artículo de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceso_(inform%C3%A1tica)):

> Un proceso, en informática, puede entenderse informalmente como un programa en ejecución. Formalmente un proceso es "Una unidad de actividad que se caracteriza por la ejecución de una secuencia de instrucciones, un estado actual, y un conjunto de recursos del sistema asociados".

Para el sistema operativo un proceso es una estructura de información acerca de los datos de un programa en ejecución, aunque puede que ese proceso no esté en ese momento haciendo uso de la CPU. Por ejemplo, mientras espera que finalice una llamada a un dispositivo de entrada/salida ese proceso estará en un estado latente (*sleep*) y no hará uso de la CPU.

Varios procesos pueden disputarse el uso de la/s CPU/s, de modo que el sistema operativo le puede asignar intervalos de tiempo a cada proceso para que haga uso de la CPU, incluso recordar en qué CPU física o núcle fue ejecutado la última vez para que los datos de la caché puedan ser reutilizados. Esa parte del sistema operativo se llama [planificador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planificador).

Teniendo en cuenta esto, respondo tus preguntas:

#### 1.- ¿El proceso en qué parte del procesador se ejecuta? O realmente lo que se ejecuta del proceso siempre son los hilos y todos los procesos tienen mínimo un hilo. En este caso lo que se ejecutaría del proceso siempre sería este hilo en el núcleo. (esto es deducción mía porque no encuentro información de esto en ningún sitio)

En la [unidad de procesamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidad_de_proceso).

Cualquier programa que se ejecuta en la CPU es analizado por la [unidad de control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidad_de_control), mediante la obtención de la memoria del microcódigo a ejecutar, su decodificación y, por último, su ejecución por parte de la unidad de procesamiento.

Da igual que sea un hilo, un proceso, para la CPU es un programa que debe ejecutar de manera secuencial instrucción a instrucción. El concepto de proceso e hilo pertenecen al sistema operativo, no al procesador.

#### 2.- ¿En un procesador de varios núcleos se pueden ejecutar de forma paralela varios hilos de distintos procesos?

Sí.

Un sistema con varios procesadores físicos o varios núcleos por procesador físico podrá ejecutar de manera simultánea varias instrucciones en paralelo.

Donde "ejecutar" podríamos considerarlo como la acción en bloque de leer la instrucción a ejecutar de memoria, decodificarla y, finalmente, ejecutarla.

Pero, en la parte de la ejecución podría haber un acceso a memoria que está siendo bloqueado por el acceso a memoria de otro procesador. La ejecución de esa instrucción queda congelada hasta que quede libre el bus de memoria.

#### 3.- ¿En un núcleo de un procesador se pueden ejecutar de manera concurrente varios hilos de distintos procesos?

No.

Aunque el sistema operativo, a través del planificador, puede darte la sensación de que ejecuta múltiples procesos en paralelo en sistemas con un único procesador, en realidad está multiplexando el uso de la CPU por turnos a cada proceso, nunca dos a la vez.

En procesadores multihilo (2 en arquitectura x86_64 y hasta 4 en procesadores PowerPC) se podría considerar que sí, pero realmente tiene limitaciones al trabajar la misma parte de ese núcleo físico con cierto tipo de tareas al mismo tiempo en cada una de las "hebras".

Las tecnologías multihilo usan "trucos" para aprovechar momentos de inactividad del núcleo o algunos de sus componentes para realizar o avanzar la ejecución de un segundo proceso.